# Native ads: How to access URL for open browser with CustomTemplateAd's

Tags: android, admob, google-dfp

I'm implementing native custom template ad in my android app and in my code I am fetching and rendering custom template ad in my view. I want to open the `Webview` when the user clicks on the ad with the click-through `URL` that I set in my dfp portal but I don't see any method or documentation on how to get hold of that `URL`.

from `nativeCustomTemplateAd.getAvailableAssetNames();` I get only three key none of them are URL key. how I get URL which is in **"f"** as shown in the screenshot.

[image]
[image]

How to get ad URL?

Comment: I found solution : The forCustomTemplateAd method accepts an OnCustomClickListener. If you pass a listener object in, the SDK instead invokes its onCustomClick method and takes no further action. If you pass a null value as the listener, however, the SDK falls back to the deeplink and/or destination URLs registered with the ad.
So I found my click url action with pass null parameter instead of OnCustomClickListener

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this scenario. The Click-Through URL was not accessible from the NativeCustomTemplateAd object. To open the ad in a webview when use clicks on it, Add the Click through URL in an optional field such as **StandardURL** and when user clicks on the ad, get it by calling `nativeCustomTemplateAd.getText("StandardURL").toString()` and load this url in a webview.